# EC2 Error: Cannot find module '../commands'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

`your text`I have deploy my backend NestJS app in aws elastic beanstalk, for that I am using aws codebuild to select the github repo and deploy that app by codepipeline in elastic beanstalk, also I have RDS postgresql db outside from elastic beanstalk. I want to mention that everything is ok, no errors. I have only one error on my ec2 instance, which was created my beanstalk, when it wants to run the app, it get this error:

> nestjsapp@0.0.1 start
> nest start
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
> throw err;
> Error: Cannot find module '../commands'
> Require stack:
> /var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/nest
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/nest:5:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12) {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/nest' ]
> Node.js v18.18.2`

But I want to mention also, that in our project we do not have ../commands module. Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.